# Can my PC run modern games with 4GB of RAM?

Tags: pc, performance

Can my PC run games like GTA 5, Mass Effect Andromeda, Witcher 3?

My question is specific to RAM requirements for the game.

My system specs are:

- CPU: i3 7100 Kaby Lake
- RAM: 4 GB Adata
- GPU: Nvidia Zotac 1050 Ti 4 GB

If yes, at what settings I can play them?
Or should I go for increasing my RAM to 8 GB or 16 GB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

No, you need more RAM based on the minimum system requirements of the games. The games minimally require 6-8GB of RAM.

**Long Answer:**

Without really looking too deeply into the minimum system requirements I would personally recommend upgrading your ram. 4GB of RAM is on the verge of being useless in a gaming computer.

Looking into the minimum system requirements of Witcher 3 and assassin's creed Origins, both require at least 8GB of RAM.

As per what settings you would be able to play the games on all depend on the graphics card and the rest of your system. I would just go with whatever the recommended settings are when you launch the game.

Answer (score 2):

The RAM specs for those games are as follows (for 1920x1080 resolution):

```
Game          Minimum     Recommended
GTAV          4GB         8GB
ME:Andromeda  8GB         16GB
Witcher 3     6GB         8GB
```

For modern games and to keep your PC reasonably future-proof you'll want to look at the higher end - 16GB at least, maybe even 32 if you can manage.

Comment: This is a good answer to a very down-voted question, why is this being down-voted?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 Most likely because it's oddly specific and can easily be Googled. You could literally copy+paste it into a search engine and get the answer.

Comment: @SPYBUG96 Typically, answering questions that are off topic is frowned upon. Hence you may incur some down votes.

Comment: @TimmyJim Yeah I realize that now